# Google Cloud Java Client library not compiling through gradle

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gcloud, gcloud-java

I'm using google cloud endpoints as the backend server and google cloud storage to host the images for the project.
Now I want to make an endpoint to upload a image file to the google cloud storage bucket.
For that I have ended up on [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java#google-cloud-storage) google cloud java client github page

They say, if you want to compile using gradle, then use this line:

> compile 'com.google.gcloud:gcloud-java:jar:0.1.0'

but when I add this line to the gradle file, then it gives error while compiling:

> Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.gcloud:gcloud-java:jar

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have central maven repo configured for your gradle build?

Comment: I have jcenter repository configured, and the problem was solved by using compile 'com.google.gcloud:gcloud-java:0.1.0'....as told by mziccard here:https://goo.gl/ALXq7R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was [answered over on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/issues/436), but just for posterity, it looks like with Gradle the line should be

```
compile 'com.google.gcloud:gcloud-java:0.1.0'
```

(Note this removed the `:jar` piece.)